# Broken code(newbie code), Loop not working as intended

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that prompts people to re-enter their name if they put numbers or special characters in them. (Working on numbers first then I will do special characters).

My for loop is not acting as I expected it to. I wanted my for loop to go over every char in name[256], and check if it is `a ... z || A ... Z`. However, I am running into problems. See output below the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int age;
    int i = 0; //for the loop
    float height, weight;
    char name[256];
    char reason[256];

    printf("--------------------------------\n");
    printf("WRITE YOUR INFORMATION\n");
    printf("--------------------------------\n");

    printf("NAME      : ");
    fgets(name, 256, stdin);
    while (name[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (name[i] != (name[i] >= 'a' && name[i] <= 'z') || (name[i] >= 'A' && name[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            printf("Enter your name again, no numbers.\n");
            i++;
            printf("NAME      : ");
            fgets(name, 256, stdin);
        }
        break;
    }
    
    printf("AGE       :");

    return 0;
}
```

This is when my input for fgets function is br4ndon, sure it worked good, but when i typed in br4ndon again, it passed by... it wasn't supposed to.

```
--------------------------------
WRITE YOUR INFORMATION
--------------------------------
NAME      : br4ndon
Enter your name again, no numbers.
NAME      : br4ndon
AGE       :
```

Now this is an input with brandon

```
--------------------------------
WRITE YOUR INFORMATION
--------------------------------
NAME      : brandon
Enter your name again, no numbers.
NAME      : brandon
AGE       :
```

How can I make sure that it only prompts to re-enter name if the charachter contains anything but `a ... z || A ... Z`?

Comment: Where are you learning C++ from? There are quite a few problems here, and many of them could be avoided simply by writing proper C++ (by which I mean using `std::string`). Start lots smaller. Find out how to have the user input a name, find out how to check a string for numbers, then add your loop on top. It might seem "wrong" to have to start over but I assure you it will go much quicker and will save you future headache

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++? Ther are different languages. Your code looks like pure C code. Please [edit] your question and make that clear.

Comment: try adding this if condition if(name[i] >=1 && name[i] <=9)..

Comment: @Jarvis__-_-__ you probably mean `'1'` and `'9'` instead of the numerical values. Also what about `'0'`?

Comment: I'd like to remove the C++ tag.

Comment: You include `ctype.h`. Why don't you use any of the functions provided there? You might take a look at `isalpha` and `isdigit`.

Comment: You should start learning how to use a debugger. Run your program in a debugger and see where execution flow goes along. And watch values of variables. Especially look at value of `i` when you read the line again in your loop.

Comment: @Tas,@Jabberwocky, sorry for the confusion, yes its coded in C. I planned my programming journey that starts from learning the basics of C and learning the lowest level of programming language and then choose which language I would need in the future. I am planning to learn front end dev ( HTML and CSS ) on parallel to C. Again, sorry about the confusion

Comment: @Gerhardh, I will definitely look through the headers more detailed to see what functions are available to me. Also thank you for your tip on learning how to use debugging tool. I tried to use it on Visual Studio 2019, but it seems like i'm doing something wrong and it doesn't show. I will figure it out. Appreciate the comments!

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in your code:

- you mix up the loop for the input of name and the loop that checks if none of the chars of `name` is anything else than a letter.
- you omit the removal of the trailing `\n` after `fgets`(read the fgets documentation)
- the condition `name[i] != (name[i] >= 'a' && name[i] <= 'z') || (name[i] >= 'A' && name[i] <= 'Z')` makes no sense at all.

You want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int age;
  float height, weight;
  char name[256];
  char reason[256];

  printf("--------------------------------\n");
  printf("WRITE YOUR INFORMATION\n");
  printf("--------------------------------\n");

  while (1)
  {
    printf("NAME      : ");
    int nameok = 1;
    fgets(name, 256, stdin);
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;          // remove the `\n` at the end of name
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++)
    {
      if (!(name[i] >= 'a' && name[i] <= 'z') || (name[i] >= 'A' && name[i] <= 'Z'))
      {
        // character not included in A..Z or a..z
        nameok = 0;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (nameok)
      break;   // name is OK, we end the while loop

    // name not OK: ask again
    printf("Enter your name again, no numbers.\n");
    continue;
  }

  printf("AGE       :");

  return 0;
}
```

There is still room for improvement:

Examples:

- you should use `isalpha` from `ctype.h` (which you include already) instead of the awkward `!(name[i] >= 'a' && name[i] <= 'z') || (name[i] >= 'A' && name[i] <= 'Z')` condition.
- you should make a function that asks for the name
- `fgets(name, 256, stdin)` should rather be `fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin)`, so if you change the size of the `name` array, you only need to change it in one place

Comment: strcpn() function looks awesome, just looked it up on google. `name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;` This statement, you search for \n and count the string length in name and put the string length found as name[*found string legnth*]. This is cool. Never thought about this. My question is why remove it though? Is it because It would trigger the if function even when the names are just alphabets?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer _Is it because It would trigger the if function even when the names are just alphabets?_ yes, obviously. And you don't need the extra `\n` is only causes hassle.